# Bind text to a drop down list value on page load using angular 8

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, angular-ui-router

I'm having problem in populating values from database to a drop down list in Angular components.

getting value from database. when am assigning the value in html page it is not working.

[image]

Code:

```
public categoryList;

ngOnInit(): void {
    debugger;
    let adminid = localStorage.getItem('adminID');
    this.api.getAllCategories(adminid).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.categoryList = data;
    })
}
```

Html display code:

```
<div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-12 mb-1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h6>Choose Category<span style="color:red">*</span></h6>
    <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="helpInputTop" /> -->
    <select class="form-control">
      <option [value]="item.CategoryName" *ngFor="let item of categoryList">
        {{item.CategoryName}}
      </option>
    </select>
    <span *ngIf="f.ChooseCategory.touched && f.ChooseCategory.invalid" class="invalid-form">
      <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="f.ChooseCategory.errors.required">This field
        is required!</small>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is the output:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the data type of `categoryList` in the question?

Comment: @YongShun public categoryList;

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: @DRASHTIDOBARIYA https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1uinrv?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Please check out this edited stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bjafsk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: It is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a regular Array instead of Observable.

try using this approach:

```js
//use a BehaviorSubject
private _categoryList = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
categoryList$ = this._categoryList.asObservable();

constructor() {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    debugger;
    let adminid = localStorage.getItem('adminID');
    this.api.getAllCategories(adminid).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this._categoryList.next(data);
   })
  }
```

and in your html use the `async` pipe to subscribe that list:

```html
...
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of categoryList$ | async">
 <option [value]="item.CategoryName">
   {{item.CategoryName}}
 </option>
</ng-container>
...
```

Comment: How to implement behaviorsubject

Comment: import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs"; is it correct?

Comment: Same output text not disaplayed

Comment: Although implementation using async pipes is considered good practice, it is not mandatory for working of select

Answer (score 0):

> Try this!

```
categoryList: any[] = [];

constructor() {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    debugger;
    let adminid = localStorage.getItem('adminID');
    this.api.getAllCategories(adminid).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.categoryList = data;
    })
}
```

> In html

```
<select dropdown class="form-control">
      <option *ngFor="let item of categoryList" [value]="item.CategoryName">
        {{item.CategoryName}}
      </option>
    </select>
```